# How to remove directory in web.config?

Tags: asp.net, .htaccess, iis, web-config

I tried hard but maybe not enough, still, I just want to achieve this :

mysite.com/en
=> mysite.com

and so on :

mysite.com/en/page1
=> mysite.com/page1

```
<rule name="Redirect to en version" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)\/en(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="en/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
```

Obviously it doesn't work and i'm getting crazy with regex.

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 0):

you need to disable directory browsing from IIS or from the web.config

```
<configuration>
  <location path="Secured">
    <system.webServer>
      <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```